# Replacing a char in Ruby with another character

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, replace

I'm trying to replace all spaces in a string with '%20', but it's not producing the result I want.

I'm splitting the string, then going through each character. If the character is " " I want to replace it with '%20', but for some reason it is not being replaced. What am I doing wrong?

```
def twenty(string)
  letters = string.split("")
  letters.each do |char|
    if char == " "
        char = '%20'
    end
  end

  letters.join
end

p twenty("Hello world is so played out")
```

Comment: So what? What is your question?

Comment: Why not `string.gsub! ' ', '%20'`

Comment: Thanks @August, but just out of curiosity why is the way I'm doing it not working?

Comment: @Hotconnection Because changing the block parameter to a different object doesn't update the array entry.

Comment: Please mark some answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`URI.escape(...)` for proper URI encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#escape-method):

```
require 'uri'
URI.escape('a b c') # => "a%20b%20c"
```

Or, if you want to roll your own as a fun learning exercise, here's my solution:

```
def uri_escape(str, encode=/\W/)
  str.gsub(encode) { |c| '%' + c.ord.to_s(16) }
end

uri_escape('a  b!c') # => "a%20%20b%21c"
```

Finally, to answer your specific question, your snippet doesn't behave as expected because the `each` iterator does not mutate the target; try using [`map` with assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (or `map!`) instead:

```
def twenty(string)
  letters = string.split('')
  letters.map! { |c| (c == ' ') ? '%20' : c }
  letters.join
end

twenty('a b c') # => "a%20b%20c"
```

Comment: +1 `URI.escape('a b c')` is the right way to handle the problem. There are more values than a space that need to be encoded that the OP needs to consider/handle, and the URI class will correctly do them. Rolling his own is OK as a learning exercise but pre-built wheels are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to first split the string on spaces, you could do this:

```
def twenty(string)
  string.split(' ').join('%20')
end

p twenty("Hello world is so played out")
  #=> "Hello%20world%20is%20so%20played%20out"
```

Note that this is not the same as

```
def twenty_with_gsub(string)
  string.gsub(' ', '%20')
end
```

for if

```
string = 'hi                there'
```

then

```
twenty(string)
  #=> "hi%20there"
twenty_with_gsub(string)
  #=> "hi%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20there"
```